# HTML5 Details/Summary Open at Top Close From Bottom

Tags: html, css, summary

I'm using HTML5's Summary/Details tags to hide/show extra text on a documentation page.  The extra text is lengthy and the open/close nature of the summary tag is that you have to click on the summary line to make it both open and close the details block.  This means that after scrolling down through the length of the long text you must scroll back up to the summary tag in order to click to close it.

I would like to be able to click on the bottom of the details segment to close it.  Using CSS, I am able to add a 'close' triangle at the bottom of the detail segment.  What can be done (preferably in CSS) to cause a click on the triangle to close the detail block?

```
details[open]:after {
   content:'▲';
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below is a CSS only solution, just use `::after` on `<summary>` and absolute positioning.

```css
details.test {
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px 0;
}

details.test[open]>summary::after {
    display: inline-block;
    content: "close";
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<details class="test">
  <summary>Example</summary>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
  </p>
</details>
```

Comment: Nice!  It works well - thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it can be done using CSS. But you can use javascript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>
function closeDetails() {
    document.getElementById("details").removeAttribute("open");
    window.location = "#details";
}
</script>

<details id="details">
  <summary>Show Details</summary>
  <p>yadda yadda</p>
  <button onclick="closeDetails()">Close Details</button>
</details>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That has the unfortunate effect that when the details block closes you are still positioned down on the page and now have to scroll back up through text you have not even read yet!  Strange.  It behaved that way on Safari, FireFox and Chrome.  That seems to me to be a fault with how the details/summary tags were implemented (or spec'd).  After closing, you should end up where you started.

Comment: added to the javascript function:    window.location = "#details";

Comment: Thanks but that did not help.

Comment: Oops.  It DOES work - I made an error.  Thanks.  It's not how I would like it to work but it does get the job done.

Answer (score 3):

Since there were no other answers I’ll mark Sartoris’ as the correct one.

In case anyone else wants to use to it, I took the liberty of embellishing it a bit so that it would work with more than one ‘details’ element on a page and be a bit more generic.  In this way the same function and close button definition can be used for all ‘details’ blocks as long as each has a unique ID.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>
function closeDetail(detailsElement) {
    detailsElement.removeAttribute("open");
    window.location = '#' + detailsElement.id;
}
</script>

<details id="details">
  <summary>Show Details</summary>
  <p>yadda yadda</p>
  <button onclick="closeDetail(this.parentElement)">▲</button>
</details>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nice! To drop the need for an id, you could use `detailsElement.scrollIntoView()`